# Forecasting time serie data

Tags: r, date

I have a data set with closing date of equity rate VIX. My excercise is to forecast 300 points from last date and compare it with actual historical data. A snippet of the 1826 observations of my data looks like

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close
02/01/2004  17.96   18.68   17.54   18.22
05/01/2004  18.45   18.49   17.44   17.49
06/01/2004  17.66   17.67   16.19   16.73
07/01/2004  16.72   16.75   15.5    15.5
08/01/2004  15.42   15.68   15.32   15.61
09/01/2004  16.15   16.88   15.57   16.75
12/01/2004  17.32   17.46   16.79   16.82
13/01/2004  16.6    18.33   16.53   18.04
14/01/2004  17.29   17.3    16.4    16.75
15/01/2004  17.07   17.31   15.49   15.56
16/01/2004  15.4    15.44   14.9    15
20/01/2004  15.77   16.13   15.09   15.21
21/01/2004  15.63   15.63   14.24   14.34
22/01/2004  14.2    14.87   14.01   14.71
23/01/2004  14.73   15.05   14.56   14.84
26/01/2004  15.78   15.78   14.52   14.55
27/01/2004  15.28   15.44   14.74   15.35
28/01/2004  15.37   17.06   15.29   16.78
```

The code generate a forecast that is a flat and I would like to plot in the same figure historical data. How can I do this?

```
r_vix=diff(log(VIX[,"Close"]))
fit_1step <- auto.arima(r_vix[1:15])
h=300
forecast_1step = forecast(fit_1step, h=h)
plot(forecast_1step, xaxt="n",type="b")
plot_labels = 5
axis(1, at=seq(0,length(r_vix)+h-1,plot_labels), labels=VIX$Date[seq(2, length(r_vix)+h,plot_labels)] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that you're trying to represent dates using `ts` objects.  In general, `ts` is used with data which has been sampled at equispaced points in time such as daily, weekly, or monthly.  Your time series is missing data for weekends and probably some holidays so `ts` isn't appropriate and isn't required for by the forecasting functions. `auto.arima` can use a vector containing the data.  Your only issue seems to be to have dates displayed on the chart created by the plot function for `forecast` objects.  An example of how that could be done is shown below.

```
library(forecast)
r_vix <- diff(log(VIX[,"Close"]))[-1]
num_train <- 1826           # number of points used to calculate ARIMA model
fit_1step <- auto.arima(r_vix[1:num_train])
h <- 300                    # number of forecast points
forecast_1step = forecast(fit_1step, h=h)
plot_start <- 1000          # number of points at start of data series omitted from plot
plot(forecast_1step, xaxt="n", xlim=c(plot_start, num_train+300), ylim=range(r_vix))
data_fcst_pts <- num_train:(num_train+h)    # range of data points in forecast interval
points(data_fcst_pts, r_vix[data_fcst_pts],col="blue", type="p", pch=16)
plot_labels <- 126      # interval between x-axis major tick marks
axis(1, at=seq(0,length(r_vix)+h-1,plot_labels),  
     labels=VIX$Date[seq(2, length(r_vix)+h,plot_labels)] )
```

UPDATE

Code has been updated to omit data at the beginning of the time series from the plot and to plot data points for the forecast interval.  Plot is shown below.
[image]

An excellent explanation of the results and forecasts for ARIMA models is the OText book by Rod Hyndman especially the section [ARIMA modelling in R](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7) .  Professor Hyndman is the author of the `forecast` package.  More specifically, if you're trying to forecast VIX as a measure of S&P 500 volatility using ARIMA models, you'll probably want to consider the some of the many studies using ARCH or GARCH methods.  A place to start might be [Volatility Forecasting I: GARCH Models](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~almgren/timeseries/Vol_Forecast1.pdf)

Comment: Hi WaltS, I have edited my original question. There are still some issues. Is there a reason why you set h->6, I would imagined it to be 300 that is my forecast period.

Comment: I set h <- 6 since only 18 data points were included in your example and 12 were used for training the ARIMA model.  You can use 300 with the full data set.